# How to tune a GTK theme? Is there an exhaustive list of properties?

Tags: gtk, themes, gtk2

I'm trying to make GTK-based applications look more compact by customizing a theme, as suggested by [an answer](https://superuser.com/questions/533090/how-to-make-fillers-in-gtk-applications-smaller) for my other question.

I reduced some values I saw in the `gtkrc` and it got better, but not enough.

I want to shrink it further:

---

[image: Customized GTK theme with areas I want to remove]

---

How to do it?

Are there any tools helps me to adjust various paddings or at least show me the exhaustive list of properties I can set in gtkrc? Is there a document with full list of properties can be in `gtkrc`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try [gtkparasite](http://chipx86.github.com/gtkparasite/), which is a Firebug-like for GTK+.  You have to run it as:

```
$ GTK_MODULES=gtkparasite my_program
```

And then you can inspect the properties of each widget, change its values, etc. In the web page you will also see a screencast on how to use it.

Comment: Seems to be the main problem is GtkVBox and GtkNotebook. I check all properties visible in gtkparasite, but still can't remove that gray areas. All "border", "spacing", "padding" etc. values are 0, but still there are some margins. Why can't I set things to negative values to allow overlap?..

Comment: Because the widget model is based on containers (ie. widgets containing other widgets), so no overlapping is possible.

Comment: Additionally, you can look for the attributes Expand and Fill.  Expand (if True) allows the child to receive extra space when the parent grows and Fill (if True) gives the child extra space (or used as padding).  Certainly, no negative numbers for the reason explained by @liberforce.